# Why is dependency injection better than using factories?

Tags: oop, language-agnostic, dependency-injection

I've been reading up on dependency injection and I understand the appeal of specifying dependencies in XML, as is done in many frameworks. I work on a large system where we normally call factories to get concrete objects, and am struggling to understand why manually injected dependencies as shown [in this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection#Manually_injected_dependency) are supposedly any better.

It seems to me that calling a factory is better because:

1. Calling code doesn't need to know or care that a particular dependency exists.
2. Calling code doesn't need to change if new dependencies are added to the callee.
3. Calling code doesn't need to have any logic dedicated to choosing the concrete instance to inject.

It seems to me that dependency injection only offers benefit when the calling code *has* to decide on the concrete class for the dependency. Almost like "Here's my data, now process it."

Is there something I missed?

**Update:**
To clarify, our existing code mostly calls the factory directly. So to get a new Ball object, you'd see code like this:

```
Ball myBall = BallFactory.getObject();
```

A lot of those factories are implemented to allow run-time registration of new concrete object types - a plugin framework.

So after looking at some of the initial comments it seems like with DI my calling code would not normally pass in the Ball object, but instead the BallFactory. I guess the benefit of that is that the class may be more generic, since it doesn't even have coupling to the factory it  uses.

Comment: Are you passing those factories as arguments to the requiring objects? Then that's *dependency injection* as well.

Comment: Are you talking about factory classes or static factory methods ? Anyway, factories are how you usually implement the dependency injection.

Comment: Dependency Injection does the work of factory FOR YOU, INSTEAD OF YOU. That is the reason (assuming you are using a dependency injection framework).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither is "better" than the other; you can use dependency injection by itself, factories by themselves, or a combination of these.

Also all the 3 points you mentioned about factories are equally valid for dependency injection. Remember that the dependency can be injected at any point in time, not necessarily by the immediate "calling code". In fact, this is what a DI framework does for you -- it is basically a giant factory that creates your main application object and injects all the dependencies for you.

Explicitly using factories is only useful when your code needs to be able to create new instances of a dependency at runtime. Otherwise, it's much simpler to simply use a DI framework to inject all static dependencies during application startup.

Answer (score 3):

Dependency injection helps when unit testing. It allows you to separate and isolate the functionality of your class, because any of it's dependencies can be injected (and therefore also mocked) into the class. This is particularly useful if the dependencies access external resources, such as DBs.

I read an article recently that demonstrated the advantages of dependency injection in testing. It's specifically about static methods but the same could apply with factories.

http://misko.hevery.com/2008/12/15/static-methods-are-death-to-testability/

Like @deceze says though, if you inject your factories you get the best of both worlds...

Comment: I'm not a particularly big fan of that article by Miško. It does make a very convincing point, but it is way too extremist IMO. Static methods are perfectly useful, you just need to be careful *were* you use them. Just keep that in mind when reading it.

Comment: I agree, it is extreme but it makes valid points, mayb just take it with a pinch of salt.

Comment: You could still set up the static factories to be configurable at run-time for your unit tests. You don't need dependency injection to do that.

Answer (score 2):

It is often useful to use dependency injection and abstract factory in combination - but for two separate reasons. The reason for using (manual) **dependency injection** is that it allows you to inject a special object during unit testing. If your design depicts that the calling code shall not be responsible for creating object (as of your 1-2-3 bullets), then the supplied dependency shall be an instance of an **abstract factory**. The object to which is is injected will use the factory to create objects whenever it needs to.

Suppose you use two factories to produce dependencies (here just one dependency, Dice) for easy and hard games of backgammon:

```
public class EasyGameFactory implements GameFactory
{
  Dice createDice()
  {
    return new LuckyDice();
  }
}

public class NormalGameFactory implements GameFactory
{
  Dice createDice()
  {
    return new RandomDice();
  }
}
```

For unit testing purposes you would really prefer to use neither of the Dice implementations, so you write a special implementation of GameFactory:

```
public class CustomGameFactory implements GameFactory
{
  private Dice mDice;

  public CustomGameFactory(Dice dice)
  {
    mDice = dice;
  }

  Dice createDice()
  {
    return mDice;
  }
}
```

This factory would not have to be part of your production code tree. You supply the factory with a special implementation of Dice through the test code:

```
public class TestBackgammon
{
  @Test public void shouldReturnDiceThrown() 
  {
    SettableDice dice = new SettableDice();
    Game game = new GameImpl(new CustomGameFactory(dice));

    dice.setDice(new int[] {4, 5});
    game.nextTurn();
    assertArrayEquals(new int[] {4, 5}, game.diceThrown());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using dependency injection or not is a bit like the difference in C between using `printf` and using `fprintf`. Caller gains flexibility at the cost of having to make a choice. When the caller doesn't want flexibility (for example if all of your program's output goes to stdout, never stderr or a file), flexibility is a pure burden, since the caller always has to pass the same "correct" value.

If you see dependency injection as a pure burden, that means your callers aren't really using it.

Your points 1 and 3 both say, "the calling code has less freedom to influence what happens", which is not always an advantage. Test code in particular benefits from injecting dependencies, but there may also be situations where callers want flexibility for other reasons. Do you log with `printf`, or do you log by calling functions on an injected logger?

Point 2 comes down to how you evolve your APIs. Yes, if the original design needs to change then by using fixed, hidden dependencies you can shield the API from reflecting that change. Sometimes you can maintain the old API with a default value of the new dependency, and add a new method/constructor with an extra parameter somewhere.

All that said, standard libraries in languages I've used don't demand a huge amount of dependency injection. So you're not alone in thinking that your APIs don't need it, but I suspect you could get more out of it internally than you are at the moment. For example, can you test your networking code without connecting to a remote machine? If not, consider whether that part of your test procedure would be easier, faster, and give more accurate diagnostics, if you could.